# C++ Can you cast an object using a reference

Tags: c++, casting

I have a quick question which is probably a bit silly, but hopefully someone might be able to clear things up for me.

Basically, I have a class 'Test' that has a parameter object stored of type 'A', where there are several other classes like 'B', 'C', 'D' which all extend 'A'.

I am wondering if I can use this parameter (ObjectType) to create a new object of that type, i.e. use it when casting.

I can do the following to create a new object of the parent type

`AA* NewObject = SpawnObject<AA>();`

But I am wondering if I can do anything that allows me to use the parameter I have stored, i.e. if the parameter is an object type 'B' it would know to do:

`AA* NewObject = SpawnObject<AB>();`

i.e. essentially I am asking if there is any way to achieve the following, where ObjectType is the stored parameter

`AA* NewObject = SpawnObject<ObjectType>();`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try this:

```
struct A
{
    ~virtual A() = default;
    // ...
};

struct Test
{
    explicit Test(std::unique_ptr<A> a) : a_(std::move(a)) {}

    std::unique_ptr<A> a_;
};

template <typename T>
Test * SpawnObject()
{
    return new Test(std::make_unique<T>());
}
```

Usage:

```
struct B : A {};

Test * p = SpawnObject<B>();
```

Of course you shouldn't use naked `new` at all:

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<Test> SpawnObject()
{
    return std::make_unique<Test>(std::make_unique<T>());
}
```

You can also extend the maker function to forward arbitrary arguments to the derived class constructors in case they don't all have the same constructor signature. Or you might not bother with the maker function at all and just instantiate `Test` objects directly, using the appropriate kind of `make_unique` for the constructor argument.

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically set the object type in the command here:
Test* p = SpawnObject<B>(); 
i.e. make Test* the actual class type of the ObjectType variable

Comment: @PectusExcavatum: You can register factory functions with a string-based key that you can read from the user.